# How to make window function work on Redshift tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two codes below and my goal is just to list the columns and use the ROW_NUMBER() window function.

My code gives me this error:

```
SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
```

The "information_schema.columns" code i am using below is working in MS SQL Server on which I would assume looking at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_WF_ROW_NUMBER_WF.html) should also work as well.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY data_type, column_name order by ordinal_position) 
from information_schema.columns
```

I also tried PG_TABLE_DEF:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY "COLUMN","type"  ORDER BY "schemaname")  
from PG_TABLE_DEF
```

Is there a way to make it work?  Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this question - it explains why your query is failing https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/195391/70339. It suggests using `PG_TABLE_DEF` instead - but I already see the difference of `ordinal_position` not being available there.

Comment: Another option you could look at are internal tables like `pg_class`, `pg_attribute`. I don't know their exact meaning, but that's what _Aws Labs_ admin queries for redshift are using in eg. `generate_tbl_ddl` query https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql#L108

Answer (score 0):

The error you are running into is Redshift's cryptic way of saying that you are trying to access leader-node only data from the compute nodes.  Redshift is a cluster and while all local user data is stored in the compute-nodes, some system tables are stored only on the leader.  The leader-node can perform some basic querying actions but more complex functions require compute-node action.  Completely clear from the error message, right?

So you need to perform the action you desire based on only system tables that reside on the compute-nodes and this makes things a little more complex.  Below is one way you can get the information (I think) you are looking for from such tables.

```
select trim(n.nspname) as schema, trim(perm.name) as table_name, 
      trim(a.attname) AS column_name, block.col + 1 as col_num
from stv_blocklist block
join stv_tbl_perm AS perm on block.tbl = perm.id
join pg_class c on c.oid = perm.id
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace
join pg_attribute a on block.tbl = a.attrelid and block.col = a.attnum - 1
where a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
    and block.slice = 0 and block.blocknum = 0
group by 1, 2, 3, 4
order by  1, 2, 4
```